# XML & YQL (similar to SQL) - how to get a subnode's attribute?

Tags: sql, xml, yql

I'm trying to select a certain set of data with YQL, but I'm confused on how to get to sublevels with my YQL. For example, if I run this query:

select * from music.track.search where keyword="Asia"

I get this:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="22" yahoo:created="2011-07-07T16:47:41Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <Track discNumber="1" duration="0" explicit="0" flags="0"
            id="61642071" label="Mark Saliba" popularity="3" rating="-1"
            releaseYear="2008" rights="2208" title="Asia"
            trackNumber="3" url="http://new.music.yahoo.com/mark-j-saliba/tracks/asia--61642071">
            <Artist catzillaID="0" flags="2" hotzillaID="0"
                id="205843271" name="Mark J Saliba" rating="-1"
                trackCount="11"
                url="http://new.music.yahoo.com/mark-j-saliba/" website=""/>
            <Album>
```

and if I run this query:

select ID from music.track.search where keyword="Asia"

I get this:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="22" yahoo:created="2011-07-07T16:50:13Z" yahoo:lang="en-US"> 
    <results>
        <Track id="61642071"/>...
```

But what I want to do is just get the artist IDs, not the track IDs (specifically, just the first result would be fine). What is the YQL statement for that?

Comment: Did my solution below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all artist ids:

```
select Artist.id from music.track.search where keyword="Asia"
```

For just the first artist id:

```
select Artist.id from music.track.search where keyword="Asia" limit 1
```